# Unable to index/merge separate arrays into a single one

Tags: php, xampp

I have the following PHP code:

```
$file = new SplFileObject("fridge.csv");
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
foreach ($file as $row) {
    list($item, $amount, $unit, $useby) = $row;
    if(date_create_from_format('d/m/Y',$useby) > $today) {
        #echo "Use Item $item by $useby </br>";

        print_r($row);

    }
}
```

giving me the following output:

```
Array ( [0] => bread [1] => 10 [2] => slices [3] => 25/12/2017 ) 

Array ( [0] => cheese [1] => 10 [2] => slices [3] => 25/12/2017 )
```

However I need it in the following form:

```
[0] => Array (
    [0] => bread
    [1] => 10
    [2] => slices
    [3] => 25/12/2017
    )
[1] => Array (
    [0] => cheese
    [1] => 10
    [2] => slices
    [3] => 25/12/2017
    )
```

How can I merge the two arrays into a single one?

Comment: `array_merge()`

Comment: Read about [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) in PHP and [how to use them](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

```
$list = array();
$file = new SplFileObject("fridge.csv");
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
foreach ($file as $row) {
    list($item, $amount, $unit, $useby) = $row;
    if(date_create_from_format('d/m/Y',$useby) > $today) {
        $list[] = $row;
    }
}

print_r($list);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, Thanks. Didn't think to initiate list as an array. Would you also be able to tell me why I'm getting `Notice: Undefined offset:` error message at `list($item, $amount, $unit, $useby) = $row;` this particular line?

Comment: thats because probably some lines have less than 4 values. there for php returns that notice.